# NelmioApiDocBundle: generate documentation in build pipeline

Tags: symfony, nelmioapidocbundle

In a project built using Symfony 4, we use NelmioApiDocBundle version 3 plus Swagger annotations, which works fine.

In addition to browsing the API docs, I would like to create a static version of the documentation, to be generated in a build pipeline. (In your case, it’s Bitbucket Pipelines, but that shouldn’t make a difference.) NelmioApiDocBundle version 2 had a command for emitting documentation, but it seems version 3 no longer has. It’s easy to write a command which fetches `ApiDocGenerator` from the Symfony container and thus to obtain the information I want – but I can’t imagine I am the only one who wishes to do this.

Am I overlooking something? Does NelmioApiDocBundle really not have a built-in way of generating static, offline documentation?